# How can I set an incrementing value in Ursina?

Tags: python, ursina

```
from ursina import *

app = Ursina()

window.color = color.rgb(70, 0, 128)

gold = 0
gold_counter = Text(Text="0", scale=2, origin=(0, 0), background=True)
Button_1 = Button(text="+", color=color.rgb(0, 190, 0), scale=.2, x=-0.55)
Button_1.text_entity.scale *= 4
Button_2 = Button(text="Start", color=color.rgb(0, 190, 0), scale=(.5, .2, 1), x=0.55)

def gold_increase():
    global gold
    gold += 1
    gold_counter.text = str(gold)

Button_1.on_click = gold_increase
Button_3 = Button(cost=10, scale=0.2, color=color.rgb(192, 192, 192), x=-0, y=-0.25)

def gold_shop():
    global gold
    if gold >= Button_3.cost:
        gold -= Button_3.cost
        gold_counter.text = str(gold)

Button_3.on_click = gold_shop
app.run()
```

How can I set it up so that Button_3 is the "shop" so whenever the user clicks it the gold per click will be multiplied by 2, so from 1 -> 2 -> 4, etc. And if possible I'd like to increment the gold cost for "upgrading" the button by 2 (I think that's the easiest way).